# How would one disable the creation of multiple users on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, users

I am currently using Ubuntu 17.10 and I am looking for a way to disable the ability to create any more users on my system. I have several people who use this computer, but I would like for them to only use this "user". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Don't give them administrative privileges.

Comment: Or if they need sudo / admin access configure sudo to give access to only what they need and do not allow them to create new users.